# Salesforce: impersonation using the API

Tags: salesforce

I'm a Salesforce system administrator and I would like to use the Web Services API on behalf of (ie: impersonate) a Salesforce user that is part of my company.

More precisely, I'm looking for a feature similar to what Google Docs already provides: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#using_google_apps_administrative_access_to_impersonate_other_domain_users

Can this be done ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to authenticate with the API using the other user's credentials. This is a security feature that cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This is should be possible if you have login access for that user and a tool to inspect a browser cookies.

When you're logged in as the test user open a cookie browser and grab the value in the "sid" cookie.  This is a session id for that user and can be set in the headers of an api request instead of doing a login call.

I've haven't tried this.  It's possible that this session id may only be valid for the browser and not the API.  In that case you should probably just create a test user with the same profile and your email.  If all else fails just ask the user to temporarily change their password and share it with you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I need: the use case is to write an application that will archive SF documents created by all the users in my company... without having to ask for the login/password of each individual user.

Comment: By SF Documents, do you mean the documents, content, notes, attachments?  Are you trying to archive personal documents?  For most of these you can query them without having to be logged in as the user.  I'm not sure I understand the need to login as the individual user ...

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about all these types of documents and I'm not sure that when logged as admin, I can query for the personal (private) content of all my company users.