# How to limit SOQL results to those accessible to a user

Tags: salesforce

I have admin API access for my organization. I'd like to run the same SOQL query, but get back results as visible to various users in my org: running "SELECT Name FROM Account" for user A, should only return account names accessible to user A.

I know this is easy if each user provides my application with their password and security token, so I can log in as them and run the query, but I want to do this only using my admin account.

this is very similar to:

[Salesforce: impersonation using the API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10102815)

but in this case I do have access to the data, I just want to filter it as though the request came from a specific user. It looks like there's an Apex "unit testing" method called System.RunAs() which looks close, but I want to run this via REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can filter the first SOQL query using **`HasReadAccess`** from `UserRecordAccess` table.

You could try building a set of `RecordIDs` first and then using this to **filter** the Account query.

```
Set<ID> sRecordIDs = [SELECT RecordID FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = :u AND HasReadAccess = True];
Account[] accs =[SELECT ID,Name FROM Account WHERE Id in :sRecordIDs];
```

More details on the [official documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've been researching the UserRecordAccess, and it's not clear to me if it represents a logical union of "Object Records, Object Sharing, and Group Maintenance Tables" as described in the PDF "User Record Access: Under the Hood", or if it is separate, perhaps describing just Object Sharing. Any idea?

Comment: UserRecordAccess is related to Object Records and Users. You can Use that table as a wrapper of Records-Sharing-Groups. That is the only way that I know to filter data for an specific user (Your original question :)

Comment: I just did some testing, and at first glance I think this should work for me! It's a little unfortunate about the "maximum of 200 records" part, but this may be sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: This fails as of today when I tested it in a Dev Console. Error Message: Where clause must contain either RecordId = [single ID] or RecordId IN [list of IDs]. This is confirmed by the notes on this page:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm